# Combine all the keys which have same values inside a dictionary and swap keys with values and values with keys

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to combine all the keys which have same values inside a dictionary and swap keys with values and values with keys?

I am not sure if anything like this is even possible, but here is the example.

```
mydict = {'./three/failures/1.log': ['UVM_ERROR: This is one error'], './one/failures/1.log': ['UVM_ERROR: This is one error'], './two/failures/1.log': ['UVM_ERROR: This is two error']}
```

Expected output:

```
{'UVM_ERROR: This is one error': ['./three/failures/1.log', ./one/failures/1.log'], 'UVM_ERROR: This is two error': ['./two/failures/1.log']}
```

Little hint I found to find keys with same values:

```
>>> [k for k,v in a.items() if v == 'UVM_ERROR: This is one error']
['./one/failures/1.log', './three/failures/1.log']
```

Updated after trying one of the solutions:
If my dictionary doesn't have same values for any of the keys, then defaultdict doesn't work.

For example:

```
Dictionary :  {'./three/failures/1.log': 'UVM_ERROR: This is three error', './one/failures/1.log': 'UVM_ERROR: This is one error', './two/failures/1.log': 'UVM_ERROR: This is two error'}
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'U': ['./three/failures/1.log', './one/failures/1.log', './two/failures/1.log']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = {'./three/failures/1.log': 'UVM_ERROR: This is one error', './one/failures/1.log': 'UVM_ERROR: This is one error', './two/failures/1.log': 'UVM_ERROR: This is two error'}

output = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in mydict.items():
    output[v].append(k)

print output
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'UVM_ERROR: This is two error': ['./two/failures/1.log'], 'UVM_ERROR: This is one error':['./three/failures/1.log', './one/failures/1.log']})
```

`defaultdict` is derived from `dict`, so you can use it exactly how you can use `dict`. If you really wanted a pure `dict`, just do `dict(output)`.

Comment: Updated my question with observation based on your solution.

Comment: @npatel The reason it doesn't work is because in your question `mydict` had square brackets around each value, whereas they brackets aren't there in your test. I'll update. It's very simple: just change `v[0]` to `v`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group `mydict` items by values ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)):

```
mydict = {'./three/failures/1.log': ['UVM_ERROR: This is one error'], './one/failures/1.log': ['UVM_ERROR: This is one error'], './two/failures/1.log': ['UVM_ERROR: This is two error']}

from itertools import groupby

out = {}
for v, g in groupby(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda k: k[1]), lambda k: k[1]):
    out[v[0]] = [i[0] for i in g]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'UVM_ERROR: This is one error': ['./three/failures/1.log', './one/failures/1.log'],
 'UVM_ERROR: This is two error': ['./two/failures/1.log']}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not too difficult. You can do it all in-line in fact!

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
d0 = dict(zip(list(d.values()), list(d.keys())))
d0
{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
```

Comment: But what about combining the keys for which the values are same?

Comment: Oh, just saw, you want to combine all same-valued keys...hmm...not really sure about that, I'm sure there's some way to do it...